# Why don't I see all of my DB2 instances in Data Studio?

Tags: db2, ibm-data-studio

I'm running IBM Data Studio 4.1.1 in Windows 8.1. I have a copy of DB2 Express-C 10.5 on the same machine and it has two instances, the default one of DB2 and a new one I've created called inst2. When I open Data Studio, I only see the instance called DB2 but the inst2 instance doesn't appear.

How do I get my second instance and its databases to appear so that I can work with them? I've tried refreshing the Administration view and even stopping and restarting Data Studio but the second instance never appears. Do I need to do something with the instance of database in the CLP - like cataloging the database - before it will appear in Data Studio?

Also, I'm not clear if I can do commands like db2icrt and db2ilist from Data Studio. So far, it only appears to be set up to do SQL but not DB2 commands.

Any help with either question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application can only be associated with a single DB2 instance at a time (as 
controlled by the `DB2INSTDEF` environment variable (on Windows).

Data Studio has the option (enabled by default) to include all databases that have been cataloged within the default instance, which is why you see databases from only one instance.

If you want to see the other databases, you have a couple of options:

1. Manually catalog the databases from the other instance within your primary instance
2. Define new connections (JDBC) to the databases in the other instance

Data Studio can not, as far as I can tell, perform discovery to find DB2 instances, nor can it create DB2 instances.  It's intended to be primarily a remote client, even if it does rely on ssh to execute certain OS-level commands on remote machines.